# How to change the color of the Text and a SVG on hover in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

So I have the following React component which acts as a Navbar in my case. Whenever the user hovers over the navbar item it must change its color to whatever is specified. Currently, the Navbar item consists of 2 items: The Icon(SVG) and a text describing what it is.

So hovering over the component must change the color of both the text and the icon.

Here is the current code:

```
import { ReactComponent as DashboardIcon } from "../assets/ico_dashboard.svg";
```

```html
<div className="navBar">
  <ul className="nav-links">
    <li>
      <div className="divHover">
        <a href="#">
          <DashboardIcon className="navLinkHolder" height={50} />
          Dashboard
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Using this code is working on the Text inside the  which is the Dashboard but the SVG is not changing its color. How do I change the color of the SVG? I tried `fill: yellow` too but it did not work

Comment: If the icon is an **svg image**...you can't. It needs to be an actual inline SVG element.

Comment: So you mean I should use the <svg> tag and not use it as an React Component? @Paulie_D

Comment: Can you put up a working code snippet ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with React components but I do know you can't change the internals of an *image* regardless of format. so substituting the image for an actual `svg` / `use` would be the logical method.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : this solution works only on in-line svg, because the browser is able to add the `fill` property also on `svg`'s childs. It's not a basic text so the `a` is not able to fill them.

(you can just open the svg file with a text editor and copy its content)

You should apply the `:hover` pseudo-class on the svg class also!

```css
navLinkHolder:hover {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

EXAMPLE:

```css
.mylink:hover {
  fill: orange;
  color: orange;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="/" class="mylink">
    my link
    <svg width="24" height="24" class="mysvg">
      <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can separate the style too, but like this the svg and the text will behave the same way in the same time.

Comment: Its not working. Since the css is applied on the <a> tag shouldnt it apply it to the svg too?

Comment: @krishnanspace sorry, it's not working; i changed my answer and added a code snippet! Check it now

Answer (score 1):

you can add to 'path' in the SVG the 'className', so use it in parent CSS hover:

```
<svg width="24" height="24">
      <path className="myIcon" d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
</svg>
```

```
import { ReactComponent as DashboardIcon } from "../assets/ico_dashboard.svg";
```

```
<div className="navBar">
  <ul className="nav-links">
    <li>
      <div className="divHover">
        <a href="#">
          <DashboardIcon height={50} />
          Dashboard
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a:hover .myIcon{
  fill: red;
}
```

or:

```
.divHover:hover .myIcon{
   fill: red;
}
```